# AIOSEO plugin is showing some hits, they are the links of backend like css and wp-config files

Tags: php, wordpress

I wanted to add redirects to broken links on my website, so on the AIO SEO dashboard I started adding relevant redirects, however, I found out that the URLs which got hits are not only frontend links but it is also showing links such as

```
wp-config.php; 
/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/users/;
/blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml; 
//blog//wp-JSON/embed/1.0/embed?url=https://plrljewelersanddaughters.com//blog/
```

and I am worried if this is some kind of hack going on without my knowledge or what is it? can anyone please help and let me know if this is some signal related to hacking or if is it normal?

Comment: It's not a hack. there are many bots that hit too many wordpress websites to find unsecured points. I would suggest your install WordFence or any other security plugin so that you could monitor attacks and block those attackers automatically and manually.

Comment: one security plugin is already in place and some of the links that this list is showing freaks me out: it has also hit my wp-admin page 120 times, tried to access 552 links in a matter of last 3 days only, please see some more links here: /csjs/bankCheck.js /js/bankCheck.js all of this is showing in 404 log of redirect page on AIOSEO dashboard

Comment: If a security plugin is installed then it's ok. You can't stop people from hitting on those endpoints. you can just secure the endpoints and let them hit they will get an error page by your security plugin and will get blocked each time they do malicious requests.

Comment: i have the option to redirect those link requests to external sites through AIOSEO dashboard, what do you think?

Comment: You can but it's unnecessary.